# expect script failing at last prompt

Tags: expect

I'm writing a script to update firmware on multiple terminal servers. So far the script works perfect up until the last step, where I'm asked whether I'd like to reboot (yes, no)...

The CLI commands for the terminal:

```
--:#- [system_tools] cli-> download
--:#- [system_tools] cli-> install
Jun 12 23:49:19 xx.xx.com event_notify: EVT[11]:Image upgrade started. User: root. Current version: 2.5.0.12. New version: 3.1.0.13.
finish
Jun 12 23:51:34 xx.xx.com event_notify: EVT[12]:Image upgrade result. Result: 0. New firmware version: 3.1.0.13.
--:#- [system_tools] cli-> finish
--:- / cli-> reboot
Rebooting the appliance will cause all currently active sessions to be disconnected.
Are you sure you want to reboot the appliance? (yes, no)  :
```

These are the last few lines of the expect script:

```
send "finish\r"
expect "$"
send "reboot\r"
expect "Rebooting the appliance will cause all currently active sessions to be disconnected.Are you sure you want to reboot the appliance? (yes, no)  : "
send "yes\r"
```

However the `yes` does not get sent. The script ends at:

```
Are you sure you want to reboot the appliance? (yes, no)  :
```

and doesn't go any further. What am I missing here? Why isn't the `"yes\r"` sent?

Thanks

Comment: add `interact` or `expect eof` after `send "yes\r"`.

Comment: That worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's a newline "disconnected." and "Are you sure". You might want to just do this:

```
expect "Are you sure you want to reboot the appliance? (yes, no)  : "
```

As to why it waits forever, did you change the `timeout` variable in your script?

Pro-tip: debug your expect script with `expect -d script.exp`